# How can I make a method similar to Array() in Ruby (no dot syntax)?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, you can use `Array()` to wrap an element in an empty array if it wasn't already an array:

```
Array(2) => [2]
Array([2, 3]) => [2, 3]
```

How would I define a method like on my own custom class? Like `Foo()`? I'm having a hard time searching for it on the internet because I don't know exactly what's going on here.

Comment: what `foo` would return ?

Comment: Doesn't matter, just wondering how to define the method.

Comment: what's the behavior you need to write inside `foo` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit doesn't matter, he's just wondering how to define the method.

Comment: @MarekLipka May be I am missing OP's need.. :) Let's look at the answer,which would clarify this I hope...

Comment: Are you trying to provide something like Array() on your own class, or extend the basic (kernel) methods to add a new method?  Do you want to do something like a class function, class.Foo(obj), or something more like obj.Foo()?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: Really it's just a type of factory method, using the convention it has same name as the class. There is no magic that the OP perhaps expected, except maybe that Ruby finds the method (due to existence of parameters) as opposed to the Class object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Array()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) is the private method defined in `Kernel` module. So if you want your custom `Foo()` method that works in similar way, you could do:

```
module Kernel

  private

  def Foo(*args)
    # code
  end
end
```

You could also define this method in `Object` class, since `Kernel` is mixed-in to `Object`, there would be no difference.

Comment: I think `Foo` should be a private method,if OP wants to call it like `Array(2)`..as `Foo(2)`...also. As `Kernel.private_instance_methods.grep(/Array/)
# => [:Array]`..

Comment: @ArupRakshit thanks for your suggestion, I edited my anwer accordingly.